# How to maintain multiple Fragment stack or multiple child fragments inside each actionbar tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have created 3 actionbar tabs and want to open new fragment in same actionbar tab on button click event using android studio. Please let me know, how to achieve this ?

Comment: What have done so far? Post your effort .

Answer (score -1):

(edit) You have to detatch the old fragment and attach a new one. If you want to switch back to the old one just detatch the new one and reattach the old.